# Put System.Activities.Activity into Azure Cache?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, azure-caching

Can we put instances of System.Activities.Activity class (WF 4.0) into the Windows Azure Cache? We would like to compile our workflows from XAML, but this is an expensive operation to repeat. Would Windows Azure Cache support the caching of System.Activities.Activity (is that class serializable)?

Comment: Here a great article about [hosting WorkFlows in Windows Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2011/01/12/running-net4-windows-workflows-in-azure-today.aspx) but I'm not sure you can cache System.Activities.Activity I never read about it. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to use Azure cache for this. You could just use a static in-memory cache though. See http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/07/23/Caching-workflow-activities-to-increase-performance.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I'll need to build something like this, but it will need a locking mechanism so that I can have dozens of instances running in parallel and not being grabbed by two different threads.

Comment: The link has moved here: http://www.neovolve.com/2010/07/23/caching-workflow-activities-to-increase-performance/